# Мне нужно оптимизировать этот код

Tags: python, оптимизация

```
a,l = map(int,input().split())

count = 0
for i in range(1,a):
    for j in range(1,a):
        for k in range(1,a):
            if a>=i+j+k and l>=i*j*k:
                count+=1

print(count)
```

Задача:
Сколько существует троек положительных целых чисел `a`, `b`, `c`
таких, что `a+b+c <= S` и `a*b*c <= P`?

Вводятся числа `S` `P`.
Пример если числа `S=5` и `P=2`, то результат `4`.
*(Все подходящие тройки `(1,1,1)`, `(1,1,2)`, `(1,2,1)`, `(2,1,1)`.)*

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Осталось только понять что ты над этим подразумевал.

Comment: А числа могут быть одинаковыми? Формулировка задачи какая

Comment: Сколько существует троек положительных целых чисел (a,b, c) таких, что a+b+c<=S b a*b*c<=P? вводятся числа S P. программирование на питон. Пример если числа 5 и 2

Answer (score 2):

А зачем там вообще `if`, если можно сразу циклы ограничить так, чтобы условие выполнялось всегда.

```
S, P = map(int,input().split())

count = 0
for a in range(1, min(S-2, P)+1):
    for b in range(1, min(S-1-a, P//a)+1):
        for c in range(1, min(S-a-b, P//(a*b))+1):
#            print(a,b,c)
            count+=1

print(count)
```

И даже в этом случае последний цикл точно не нужен:

```
for a in range(1, min(S-2, P)+1):
    for b in range(1, min(S-1-a, P//a)+1):
        count += min(S-a-b, P//(a*b))
```

Или даже так:

```
count = sum(min(S-a-b, P//(a*b)) for a in range(1, min(S-2, P)+1) for b in range(1, min(S-1-a, P//a)+1))
```

Последний вариант вычисляет результат за 5 секунд для S=5000 и P=10<sup>12</sup> *(где-то видел, что это граничные условия для данной задачи)* : `count = 20_820_835_000`.